# How many items can produce light?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was wondering, leaving the torch and the jack o' lantern apart, how many items and which can produce light?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is a list of [light-emitting blocks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Light#Light-emitting_blocks) on the Minecraft Wiki.

These blocks along with the [light levels](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Light#Effects_of_light) the produce are as follows:

- [Fire](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fire) - 15
- [Jack-O-Lantern](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Jack-O-Lantern) - 15
- [Lava](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lava) - 15
- [Glowstone](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Glowstone_Block) - 15
- [End Portal Block](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Technical_blocks#End_Portal) - 15
- [End Gateway Block](https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_Gateway_(block)) - 15
- [Active Redstone Lamp](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_Lamp) - 15
- [Beacon](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Beacon) - 15
- [Sea Lantern](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sea_Lantern) - 15
- [Torch](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Torch) - 14
- [End Rod](https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_Rod) - 14
- [Lit Furnace](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Furnace) - 13
- [Nether Portal Block](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Technical_blocks#Nether_Portal) - 11
- [Redstone Ore, when touched](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_Ore) - 9
- [Active Redstone Repeater](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_Repeater)- 9
- [Ender Chest](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ender_Chest) - 7
- [Lit Redstone Torch](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_Torch) - 7
- [Magma Block](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Magma_Block) - 3
- [Brown Mushroom](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mushrooms) - 1
- [Brewing Stand](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Brewing_Stand) - 1
- [Dragon Egg](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Dragon_Egg) - 1
- [End Portal Frame](https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_Portal_Frame) - 1

While not technically blocks,  additional light sources include:

- [Sunlight](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sun) - 15
- [Sunlight when raining or snowing](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Weather#Rain_and_snow) - 12
- [Sunlight, when thundering](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Thunder) - 10
- [Moonlight](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Moon) - 4

Additionally:

> Certain blocks will only allow light to pass through diffusely. These are water and ice, which reduce light by an additional 2 levels per block, and leaves and cobwebs, which diffuse sunlight but only reduce light by the normal 1 level per block.

There are also quite a few [lighting bugs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Light#Known_Bugs) to consider.

Comment: Great summary, I think our question's been answered :)

Comment: Some blocks - in particular Magma Block - have a funny property of "remembering" the received light level and re-emitting it even when the light source is gone. This is likely a bug, although so many players like it that it's likely to be made into a feature. (place a magma block next to glowstone, being 1 block away it receives light 14. Remove the glowstone and magma block keeps shining with strength of 14 until... uh, don't remember the rules for when and how it changes. Look it up.)

Comment: ladders glow, despite the wiki saying 0 luminescence.  blocks to the side lighten a few pixels. trees can glow when placed underwater.

Answer (score 3):

In the new Aquatic Update, sea pickle also produced light from 6-15 (only if waterlogged) depend on how much pickle are there.

Comment: Conduits also produce 15 light

Answer (score 1):

Lanterns were added and I'm pretty sure they produce the same amount of light as torches, and campfires were added and I think they produce a 15, and so were lit blast furnaces and smokers (1.14 update)